# Access Google Drive locally on Chromebook via Crouton

Tags: version-control, dropbox, google-drive-api, chroot, google-chrome-os

I am using a Samsung Chromebook with the Crouton chroot environment (https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton).  This has revolutionized my view of how practical a Chromebook can be for developer-type work.  I love it.

But now I am wanting to synchronize files between my various PCs and laptops.  Using git is certainly an option, but it requires one to manually check in my work.  What if I forget?  I have been spoiled lately using either Dropbox or Google Drive to automagically keep my files all nicely synched up.  The problem now with Crouton on my Chromebook is that I do see any obvious way to have project folder synced using Google Drive.  I assume Drive would be the easier route since its a Google product.  But if Dropbox can be made to work, that would be awesome too.

Has anyone looked into this and found a workable solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I haven't attempted to get it working yet, this project allows you to mount Google Drive to your Linux file system:
https://github.com/dsoprea/GDriveFS

Comment: Thanks man.  I think GDriveFS is a great idea!  I can't wait to try it out.

Answer (score 3):

You can access the locally synced Drive folder (as used by the rest of ChromeOS) from within a `chroot` at this directory:

> /var/host/media/fuse/drivefs-[unique ID]/root/

Note that the unique ID is different on each machine (or possibly each google account?) - you will need to find this yourself.

This can also be accessed from the ChromeOS shell here:

> /media/fuse/drivefs-[unique ID]/root/

Comment: Although this comment has not received any vote, this actually does work on a chromebook.  The advantage is that the `[unique ID]` is already part of the folder name.  As a chromebook user, you don't have to work hard to find it.  Just tab-complete it at `/var/host/media/fuse/drivefs-**TAB**`

Answer (score 1):

Dropbox works fine for me within a crouton chroot.

% sudo apt-get install nautilus-dropbox

see http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/04/install-dropbox-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/ for a full description.